# Can I get around the law of not recording a phone call unless the other end knows by making the call on a speaker in my house?

Tags: united-kingdom, recording

The living room in my house is monitored by CCTV with audio. Will that be admissible in court?

Comment: What part of "you cannot record the call without permission" do you think would be avoidable by doing this?

Comment: I would not be recording the call. I would be recording my house, myself and my living room

Comment: ... while deliberately playing the call through speaker, into equipment you know is recording it, without telling or receiving permission from the other person. You end up with a recording of the call - in what world is this entire situation not exactly recording the call?

Comment: The CCTV is on all the time. It just happened that I have received the call while I was home, I used the speaker as my hands were busy. “Deliberately” is a big stretch here.

Comment: "But your honor, I didn't record the phone call, I just made an audio and video recording of the entire conversation." Really? This is like arguing that you didn't stab someone, since you both stabbed *and* killed them.

Comment: “Your honour, I didn’t record the phone call, my living room is monitored by baby monitor 24/7 and it never came to my mind that I needed to switch the baby monitor off prior to picking up the phone! Mrs X is accusing me of ignoring her orders that she informed me with on xx/yy/zzzz during that phone call. I am lucky that we don’t deleted the files off the DVR. I had zero intentions of recording the call without her permission”

Comment: If "your honour" hates one thing, then it is a smart ass. Judges are supposed to be objective and unbiased, but if you work hard enough on it, you can stop them from being objective.

Comment: Interesting thought process thinking that a recording is not a recording merely due to the method of collection. What would *you* call the audio in question if not a recording?

Comment: Noise in the background

Comment: As a general rule, courts tend not to tolerate transparent attempts at word game loopholes, or other general dickery and violations of common sense.  If your rationale can be phrased with "technically..." then you are, technically, gonna get reamed by the judge for trying to pull that off.  Some exceptions may apply to corporations; they seem to not always be held to the same "reasonable person" standard that people are, being as they're not people, and they don't really do anything at all without a contract that makes the loopholes into features rather than exploits.

Comment: If it's merely "noise in the background", how would that ever be presented to a judge if the judge was not present to hear the "noise" as it occurred?

Comment: What are you using the recording for? Are you asking if this could be admissible as evidence or what happens if the other party sues you for making it?

Comment: @Studoku the first one, as evidence in family court

Answer (score 7):

The law 'doesn't care' how the call is recorded. What matters is whether or not you should inform / should have informed the participant(s) in the circumstances.

In circumstances where you are acting as an ordinary member of the public, in the course of a purely personal or household activity, not in a journalistic capacity, regulated business or other circumstances where the rules may differ:

In the UK it is not unlawful for a private person to record a phone call without the permission or foreknowledge of the other participant(s) - provided the recording is for 'personal use'.

If you intend to share the content of the call with a third-party or make it public, then you must inform the person ahead of recording it.

If you try to use a covertly recorded call as evidence in court, the court may or may not exclude it depending on the circumstances.